# Are there any monsters that can target more than one target/creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, targeting

I noticed that the attacks in Statblocks mention **one** target (and sometimes one creature). This made me curious. I have been poring over the MM and VGtM, but have not found any monster that can make a melee/ranged attack against more than *one target* / *one creature*.

1. Do we know of any example within the 'official' books where this is more than one?
2. If it's always one, do we know of any reason why this is at all mentioned in the statblocks?

Related: [Are there any issues with creating creatures that can make multi-target melee attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131926/are-there-any-issues-with-creating-creatures-that-can-make-multi-target-melee-at)

Related: [In the descriptions of monster action options, what's the difference between "one target" and "one creature"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137504/in-the-descriptions-of-monster-action-options-whats-the-difference-between-on)

Comment: does multiattack count?

Comment: Probably not. The question is clearly about the fact of a single attack targeting multiple targets.

Comment: Related: [Can the Deathlock Mastermind's Grave Bolts be used to attack a single target twice?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159927/can-the-deathlock-masterminds-grave-bolts-be-used-to-attack-a-single-target-twi)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109735/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-illustro).

Comment: @anagkai I think multi attack is important, because that is how the stat blocks allow for multiple targets and probably the reason very few single attacks can hit multiple targets. I don't think the question is clear.

Comment: @SeriousBri The question explicitly asks for a singular attack with multiple targets, which decisively excludes multi-attack.

Comment: “A melee/ranged attack” is pretty clearly singular.

Comment: The question cites the target number specification of attacks in stat blocks which appears so far as I know or can tell only on single attacks. Multiattack on the other hand does not specify anything about targeting in most cases, except for very few instances like the TRex.

Comment: It's worth noting that whilst – as you've found – the 'one' is almost universal, the "creature" / "target" designation is not, and may be an important distinction in some situations – e.g. should your monsters decide to attack something other than player characters. Thus the phrase may not be "future-proofing", as much as to designate the type of target.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### There was one: Deathlock Mastermind (MToF, pg. 129).

The Deathlock Mastermind's attack *Grave Bolts* says:

> ***Grave Bolts.*** *Ranged Spell Attack*: +6 to hit, range 120 ft., **one or two targets**. *Hit:* 18 (4d8) necrotic damage.

I have searched through all three primary monster source books and this is the only one I found.

#### *Monsters of the Multiverse* changed "Grave Bolts" to "Grave Bolt".

With the release of *Monsters of the Multiverse*, [*Modenkainen's Tome of Foes* is obsolete](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/196284/62294). The Deathlock Mastermind received an update that changes how Grave Bolts works. Instead of Grave Bolts having "one or two targets", it now targets one creature but can be used twice:

> ***Multiattack.*** The deathlock makes two Deathly Claw or Grave Bolt attacks.
>
> ***Grave Bolt.*** *Ranged Spell Attack:* +6 to hit, range 120 ft., one target. *Hit:* 13 (3d8) necrotic damage.

Comment: Beholders and Gazers also have the language of "target up to three creatures", but they are saving throw abilities, not attack rolls.

Comment: I've found several examples of "targets up to N creatures" and "targets one or more creatures", and all of those abilities are saving throw abilities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109737/discussion-between-medix2-and-thomas-markov).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there are other attacks that specify things like a grappled.

Comment: Other examples: Tree Blight's Grasping Root can attack on creature not grappled by it, Giant Subterranean Lizard can tail under similar conditions and swallow a Medium or smaller creature grappled by it, Rug of Smothering smothers a Medium or smaller creature. Not sure you'd want all of these as honourable mentions, but maybe rework and give them as examples of why "one target" is used (i.e. that sometimes there are restrictions on what kind of target is attackable).

Answer (score 15):

### Future-proofing (up until MToF), and just being explicit for clarity

[Thomas Markov's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/170882/35259) shows that there is one monster in *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* that can target more than one creature; the Deathlock Mastermind. However, before that, the only reason for explicitly stating what is always true for each attack in *Monster Manual* and *Volo's Guide to Monsters* must have been for future-proofing, in case one day they bring out a new monster, like they eventually did in MToF.

It's also perhaps simply good practice for them to be explicit to remove any doubt that an attack was intended to target only one creature (an easy mistake for players or DMs to make when considering gargantuan creatures; I can easily imagine someone thinking "but this creature is massive, of course its tentacle attack could hit all of the party members at once" were it not explicitly stated).

Comment: I'd assumed it was to mirror the same language used by spells and abilities, including for players.